# How to manipulate array lists - Computer Science homework

Tags: java, arraylist, computer-science

In Computer Science, we are currently working on ArrayLists and manipulating them. I have run into a bit of trouble on one of the problems for homework.

You can actually do and view the homework on this website [here](http://codingbat.com/prob/p278865?parent=/home/tlsmith2@wsfcs.k12.nc.us):

I would like to know why my code (found below) is not correct.

The problem is: An array list contains a list of animals. If the animal is a cat (i.e. the animal's descrition contains the word "cat" or "Cat"), then add it to a new array list. Return the new array list of cats.

However I will show you where I am stuck.This is what I have so far (again, the small bit of information on the problem can be found using the link above.

```
public String[] catty(String[] animals) { 

    ArrayList<String> animalsList = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i=0; i<animals.length; i++)
    {
       animalsList.add(animals[i]);
    }

    ArrayList<String> catsList = cattyB(animalsList);

    String cats[] = new String[catsList.size()];
    for (int i=0; i<catsList.size(); i++)
    {
       cats[i]=catsList.get(i);
    }

    return cats;
}

public ArrayList<String> cattyB(ArrayList<String> animalsList) 
{
  for (int i=0; i<animalsList.size(); i++)
  {
    if (animalsList.get(i).indexOf("Cat")>-1 || animalsList.get(i).indexOf("cat")>-1)
    {
      animalsList.add(animalsList.get(i));
    }
    return animalsList;
  }
  return animalsList;


}
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: @August I want to know why my code is not correct. Sorry for the question being unclear. It has been edited.

Comment: `cattyB` is not creating a new `List` and adding the `Cat`s to it...

Comment: Also, make sure you have a return statement at the end of cattyB, since you only have one in a for loop currently.

Comment: @FourScore Thanks, I made the changes. But no difference.

Comment: cattyB currently adds the First Element of that passed List, if it is a cat, to the Same List and then returns from that method. Is this the behaviour you want? It looks weird.

Comment: @Tom No I want If the animal is a cat (i.e. the animal's descrition contains the word "cat" or "Cat"), then add it to a new array list. Return the new array list of cats.

Comment: Then create a new List as the first step in this method (you already know how to create new lists) add every cat to it and return that after the 'for' loop. Also remove the return statement that is inside the loop. It is not needed there.

Comment: @Tom So like this: http://notepad.cc/pecosna89

Comment: Almost. Re-think from which list you want to get the entry and to which list you want to write it. You switched them. And you're returning the wrong list.

Comment: @Tom http://notepad.cc/pecosna89 ?? this

Comment: Try it, it might/should work now.

Comment: @matthewrball You might want to tell us a: what the expected output is and b: what the actual output is. Just "It doesn't work" is not very helpful. Note that the codingbat websites even provides this information for you...

Comment: Could you, in pseudo code or plain english explain to me what the cattyB method does? If you can do that then I may be able to help you find the mistakes.

Answer (score 2):

You are adding your cats to the original list passed into the function. This is wrong. You are supposed to create a new one, add the cats to it and return it, aren't you? Do that ...

Comment: Sorry, I am very much a beginner. Could you help me out with this?

Comment: This. Hint: in the cattyB function, use a new ArrayList instead of adding more to the old list. So that only Cats/cats are added into it.

Comment: Do i need to make a new ArrayList? or do i just mention it @AimanB

Comment: Only one way to find out ;-)

Comment: @AimanB it is due at midnight and im struggling bro. comeon xD

Comment: @matthewrball if I write the code, what will you be doing? Well, ok, how about this: `return animals.stream.filter(s -> s.toLowerCase().contains("cat")).collect(Collectors.toList()))`

Comment: @Dima doesnt recognize it.

Comment: @matthewrball Create new ArrayList. In the for loop where you you call that add method, you need to add it to a different ArrayList, not AnimalsList. Otherwise it'll cause problems. That return statement inside the for loop could also cause it to only read the first value.

Comment: @AimanB Could you please show me the correct code for this problem?

Comment: @matthewrball Yes, they can. But they're trying to do something better than that. They're trying to teach you how to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

So one missing piece here was that a new ArrayList was needed in the cattyB function. Then you could parse animalsList and put names from there into the new ArrayList. Lastly, instead of returning the original animalsList that was taken in, we need to return our new ArrayList with the cats. Here's the cattyB function with corrections. I made no changes to catty. Confirmed correct on the site OP referenced.

```
public ArrayList<String> cattyB(ArrayList<String> animalsList) 
{
  ArrayList<String> newListWithCats = new ArrayList<String>();
  for (int i=0; i<animalsList.size(); i++)
  {
    if (animalsList.get(i).indexOf("Cat")>-1 || animalsList.get(i).indexOf("cat")>-1)
    {
      newListWithCats.add(animalsList.get(i));
    }
  }
  return newListWithCats;
}
```